# Pulling Function definitions out of a static C library's source code to avoid library compilation

Tags: c, static-libraries

I have a program that uses a huge library, call it libhuge (compilation takes a long time). My Makefile first compiles libhuge and archives it. Then compiles my programs source code into object files 
`gcc -c $CFLAGS $OBJS`

Then links them all to `libhuge.a`. I tried compiling without linking to that library and saw there were very few (12 functions) that were missing definitions. Is it possible to automatically pull those definitions from my `libhuge`, and compile only those functions in an object file so I won't have to compile the whole library?

Let's put it this way! I have some functions I would like to further look into from a library. How do I find their definitions?

Comment: As long as you don't change the source code of the library, there is no need to compile it again. And if it is done properly, I would avoid the trouble with extracting the functions and their dependencies, and their dependencies... Simply link to the library, linking is quite fast. -- BTW, "minutes" might be seen as fast. Did you ever try to compile a seriously professional C++ software? It can take hours.

Comment: How about I frame it this way: How do I find the definition of a function declared in the header file of a library?

Comment: Use your favorite search tool like "grep" or even (if you're on Windows) the Explorer's search box on the source tree of the library. "Grep" and its competitors offer options to search for "full word" and "case-sensitively." I bet even your editor or IDE has such search facilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rule in your Makefile that checks for the libhuge.a and only if it doesn't exist then build the libhuge.a library:

```
<path>/libhuge.a:
    <commands to build libhuge.a>

<your program>: <path>/libhuge.a
     <commands to build your code>
```

The first time when libhuge.a does not exist,  it will build the entire libhuge.a. But once the library exists, it won't build it again.